# 'senderdisconnected' event is fired up after 5-10 min after actuall disconnection

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

We have an explicit requirement to tear down the streaming when the sender disconnected.

However we can see that 'senderdisconnected' and that window.castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected() is being called only after 10 minutes after device actually left the network.

Can we somehow force Receiver to check connection more aggressively?

Comment: the onSenderDisconnected() is called as soon as a connected device is disconnected. Turn on logging in the console and watch when a connected device disconnects itself and see what happens in that callback.

Comment: @AliNaddaf, but the reason is that sender is unable to disconnect itself cause we forcefully disabling WiFi connection. I believe between Receiver & Sender there is some heartbeat protocol which fires 'senderdisconnected' after 10 minutes.

Comment: If you are forcefully doing that, why don't you disconnect before turning the wifi off?

Comment: forcefully I mean outside the app. For example app in background and we on the phone switching off the WiFi.

Comment: @AliNaddaf, one more example of this is when the device quits the network in which receiver operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
appConfig.maxInactivity = 6000;
```

Set this an you will be fine.